# Extracting a value between a long string

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract a string from a longer string in one of my columns.

Here is a sample of what I have tried:

```
df['Campaign'] = df.full_utm.str.extract('utm_campaign=([^&]*)')
```

and this is a sample of the string I am referring to:

```
?utm_source=Facebook&utm_medium=CPC&utm_campaign=April+Merchants+LAL+-+All+SA+-+CAP+250&utm_content=01noprice
```

The problem is that this only returns this:

```
A
```

The desired output in this context would be

```
April+Merchants+LAL+-+All+SA+-+CAP+250
```

Comment: @AlexandreB. sorry about that, added my desired output

Comment: kindly add sample data

Comment: the regex seems to be working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `urlparse`

**Ex:**

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse

df['Campaign'] = df["full_utm"].apply(lambda x: urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(x).query)["utm_campaign"]) 
print(df)
```